# Populate Order fields from Account

Tags: apex, controller, extension

My first controller extension here, trying to populate some customer order fields based on the Order Account selected. Not having much luck. Also uncertain if the two lines I commented out in the extension are necessary. I've seen many examples with and without them.

```
public with sharing class OE_Extension {

public Order ord;
private Account accountRec; // to get Order default values from account: Ship Via, Rep Code, AR Terms, Order Desc
//    private ApexPages.StandardController con;

public OE_Extension(ApexPages.StandardController stdCon) {
    this.ord = (Order)stdCon.getRecord();
//        con = stdCon;
    ord.Description = 'Test Con';
}

public void OnAcctChg() {
        ord.Description = 'Test 123'; // test to see if the method if even being called
        // get related accout fields to default
        List<Account> accountList = [Select ID,Ship_Via__c,AR_Terms__c,Rep_Code__c,Order_Desc__c from Account where Id=:ord.AccountID];
        if (accountList != null && accountList.size() > 0) accountRec = accountList[0]; else accountRec = null;
        if (accountRec != null) {
            system.debug('Acct list is good');
            ord.Ship_Via__c = accountRec.Ship_Via__c;
            ord.AR_Terms__c = accountRec.AR_Terms__c;
            ord.Rep_Code__c = accountRec.Rep_Code__c;
            ord.Description = accountRec.Order_Desc__c;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Order" extensions="OE_Extension">
<apex:form >
<apex:messages />
<apex:PageBlock title="Order Detail">
<apex:PageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
</apex:PageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="ordHeader">
        <apex:outputField value="{!order.OrderNumber}"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Order.AccountID}">
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onAcctChg}" reRender="ordHeader"/>
        </apex:inputfield>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Order.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Order.ShipToContactID}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.ShippingStreet}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.ShippingState}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.ShippingPostalCode}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.ShippingCountry}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.Status}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Order.ActivatedDate}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.Ship_Via__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.AR_Terms__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.Rep_Code__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Order.OwnerID}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.PONumber}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.EffectiveDate}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Order.TotalAmount}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.BillToContactID}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.BillingStreet}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.BillingCity}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.BillingState}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.BillingPostalCode}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.BillingCountry}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Order.Description}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `public Order ord;` to

`public Order ord {get;set;}`

And use that `ord` value in the form where you are referring attributes, like below.

```
<apex:outputField value="{!ord.OrderNumber}"/>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!ord.AccountID}">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onAcctChg}" reRender="ordHeader"/>
      </apex:inputfield>
<apex:inputfield value="{!ord.Name}"/>
```

Secondly, verify the SOQL query is returning records based on selected AccountId.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had tried that before, does not work. Tried it again just to check - still does not work.

Comment: what type is issue is occuring

Comment: The extension appears to be having no impact. I even tried to set some order values in the contstructor and at the start of the onchange method.  Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the controller as follow

```
public with sharing class OE_Extension {

public Order ord{get;set;}
private Account accountRec; // to get Order default values from account: Ship Via, Rep Code, AR Terms, Order Desc
//    private ApexPages.StandardController con;

public OE_Extension(ApexPages.StandardController stdCon) {
    this.ord = (Order)stdCon.getRecord();
//        con = stdCon;
    ord.Description = 'Test Con';
}

public void OnAcctChg() {
        ord.Description = 'Test 123'; // test to see if the method if even being called
        // get related accout fields to default
        List<Account> accountList = [Select ID, name from Account where Id=:ord.AccountID];
        if (accountList != null && accountList.size() > 0) accountRec = accountList[0]; else accountRec = null;
        if (accountRec != null) {
            ord.Description = accountRec.name;
        }
    }
}
```

in particolar `public Order ord;` to `public Order ord{get;set;}`.

the rest of the code is correct.